# 'Transform' : 'class' OpenGL 3D type redefinition

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, redefinition, multiple-definition-error

I am getting this compilation error:

> Error: **'Transform': 'class' OpenGL 3D type redefinition** on line 5

Here is my Transform.h:

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/transform.hpp>

class Transform
{
public:
    Transform(const glm::vec3& pos = glm::vec3(), const glm::vec3& rot = glm::vec3(), const glm::vec3& scale = glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)) :

    Pos(pos),
    Rot(rot),
    Scale(scale) {}

    inline glm::mat4 GetModel() const
    {
        glm::mat4 posMatrix = glm::translate(Pos);
        glm::mat4 rotXMatrix = glm::rotate(Rot.x, glm::vec3(1,0,0));
        glm::mat4 rotYMatrix = glm::rotate(Rot.y, glm::vec3(0,1,0));
        glm::mat4 rotZMatrix = glm::rotate(Rot.z, glm::vec3(1,0,0));
        glm::mat4 scaleMatrix = glm::scale(Scale);

        glm::mat4 rotMatrix = rotZMatrix * rotYMatrix * rotXMatrix;

        return posMatrix * rotMatrix * scaleMatrix;
    }

    inline glm::vec3& GetPos() { return Pos;  }
    inline glm::vec3& GetRot() { return Rot;  }
    inline glm::vec3& GetScale() { return Scale; }

    inline void SetPos(glm::vec3& pos) { Pos = pos; }
    inline void SetRot(glm::vec3& rot) { Rot = rot; }
    inline void SetScale(glm::vec3& scale) { Scale = scale;  }
protected:
private:
    glm::vec3 Pos;
    glm::vec3 Rot;
    glm::vec3 Scale;
};
```

I am following this tutorial series from thebennybox:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xe7FmplKAF0&t=419s

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 with C++ and OpenGL.

What is causing that error, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Probably not related but o you have include guards for your headers? If not check this link : http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/71787/

Comment: @FallaCoulibaly thanks, that fixed the problem, if you turn your comment into an answer I can mark it as the answer

Comment: Removed tags not specific to this question, added others that are more relevant, reworded some parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You to add an include guard to your header file. Check this link : [cplusplus.com/forum/general/71787](http://cplusplus.com/forum/general/71787)